# Unexptected token ^ in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex in javascript to do some replacement, but looks like JS doesn't like regex symbols; Is there a good way to escape them all. Following is my regex expression:

```
/(bower_components/[^.]+).css/g
```

Comment: Looks like you to need to escape your slash `/(bower_components\/[^.]+).css/g`

Comment: The slash in bower_components is causing the regex to end before you expect. So it's interpreting `[^.]+).css/g` as the modifiers. Your code is equivalent to doing `new RegExp('/(bower_components/', '[^.]+).css/g')`.

Comment: @Ralph ironically that's pretty much a full answer, whereas the currently visible answer is pretty much a comment. Perhaps you should make it one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to escape them you need to put a backslash `\` before each of them.

Answer (score 1):

The slash after `bower_components` is causing the Regex to end early.

Your regex is currently trying to form this object:

```
new RegExp('/(bower_components/', '[^.]+).css/g')
```

...which doesn't really make much sense.

You need to escape the slash like such:

```
/(bower_components\/[^.]+).css/g
```